# Making button click different options within UIWebView in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

I have a view controller set up with a tab bar and webView. I need to make it like that when I press the "ATC" button in the bottom of the webView, it will choose the size that the user puts in the first page, then click the "Add To Cart" button on the website. Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance.

*Images in dropbox links below*

https://www.dropbox.com/s/he0v3m39214a6qj/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-17%20at%209.44.33%20PM.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3fuvbrixlo6y5ox/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-17%20at%209.44.41%20PM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

In .h file do like this

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnATC;

- (IBAction)btnATCPressed:(id)sender;
```

In .m file  viewDidLoad do like this

```
self.btnATC.hidden = NO;
```

and ask size for your shoe then hide your button

```
 - (IBAction)btnATCPressed:(id)sender
    {
     // ask size for your shoe ......
     self.btnATC.hidden = YES;

    }
```

Comment: I dont think you understand my question. I want the "ATC" button in the WebView page to click the "Add to Cart" button within the website with the size that the user puts in the "size" text field I have. Please let me know if this helps. Thanks